# How to inject Processing Instructions with variable parameters into XML using Thymeleaf template engine

Tags: java, xml, spring, thymeleaf, processing-instruction

I am using Thymeleaf to create an XML document based on a template.

From a template (just showing a piece of it here)

```
<A>
  ...something goes here...
</A>
```

I want to produce the document

```
<A>
  <?foo bar="baz" ?>
</A>
```

where the value of the attribute `bar` varies at runtime (in this example it is `baz`) and should thus be injected from a variable.

I have been looking [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html), but haven't been able to find anything about XML Processing Instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that does the job for me:

```
<A>
  <span th:utext="${'<?foo bar=&quot;' + barValue + '&quot; ?>'}" th:remove="tag"></span>
</A>
```

It works by creating a `<span>` tag that contains the PI as text. It finally removes the tag, leaving the PI in place.

I then compose the XML document like this:

```
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("barValue", "baz");
String xml = templateEngine.process("document1", context);
```